# 500 being thrown by containerized azure web app when application throws 413 and large enough content to trigger it

Tags: azure, iis, azure-webapps, azure-web-app-for-containers

When submitting a body > 30mb (default) locally, my application correctly throws 413. However, once it reaches Azure web app (containerized) it throws a 500 instead. This seems to be caused by the IIS proxy inbetween us and container. We have tried to change the MaxBodySize in web.config inside our container/app which had no effect. There is also no web.config in /home/wwwroot/ folder to edit and no way to create one any more via advanced tools.

The issue is not the 413 error as I have setup an endpoint that just returns a 413 error code and that works fine. Only when there is a large body does this error occur.

How can I either disable the IIS proxy grabbing this error and throwing a new 500 in its place. Or set the maxAllowedContentLength on the IIS proxy to be larger then the applications so the 413 comes through?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the Azure service you are using? If you use a Linux based container, there is nothing about IIS in the big picture. The reverse proxy in between should be YARP, https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Things_You_Should_Know/kestrel_yarp.md

Comment: Yes we are using linux containers. Thank you for the information. Will investigate and restructure question should I not be able to find the solution as  a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Li states in their comment, Linux container apps use YARP not IIS as a proxy so there would never be a way to achieve this.